# Python3 Tkinter Text Widget INSERT on same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text-widget

I have a `tkinter` app in `python3` with a Text widget that I insert text into.  I would like to append inserted text on the same line as the previous insert, like so:

```
from tkinter import *

class App :

    def __init__(self):
        sys.stdout.write = self.print_redirect

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("900x600")

        self.mainframe = Text(self.root, bg='black', fg='white')
        self.mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S)) 
        # Set the frame background, font color, and size of the text window
        self.mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

        print( 'Hello: ' )

        print( 'World!' )

    def print_redirect(self, inputStr):
        # add the text to the window widget
        self.mainframe.insert(END, inputStr, None)
        # automtically scroll to the end of the mainframe window
        self.mainframe.see(END)


a = App()
a.root.mainloop()
```

I would like the resulting insert in the mainframe text widget to look like `Hello: World!`  I'm having a hard time keeping the inserted text on the same line however.  Everytime I insert, a new line is generated.

How can I keep the mainframe.insert input string on the same line without a line break?

Comment: Try inserting at a location of ``"end-1c"``, rather than ``END``.

Comment: this code can't run. Please post _actual_, _working_ code. If you edited the code so that it would actually run, it would indeed result in a text widget that had "Hello: World!", just like you want.

Comment: @jasonharper: that is not necessary. `"end"` or `END` is perfectly acceptable in this case.

Comment: @BryanOakley you're right, sorry.  I was just trying to post the relevant code, but I left out necessary items.  I fixed the OP and it correctly illustrates the problem now.  (Maybe you could change your downvote now *wink* *wink*)

Comment: problem is not `insert()` but `print()` which always add `'\n'` at the end - but it is natural. You can use `end=""` to print text without `'\n'` - try `print( 'Hello: ', end='' )`. Or use `inputStr.strip('\n')` before you `insert()` text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is not `insert()` but `print()` which always add `'\n'` at the end - but it is natural.

You can use `end=""` to print text without `'\n'`

```
print( 'Hello: ', end='' )
```

or directly

```
sys.stdout.write( 'Hello: ' )
```

---

Or in `insert()` use

```
inputStr.strip('\n')
```

But it will remove all `'\n'` - even if you will need `'\n'` ie.

```
print( 'Hello:\n\n\n' )
```

You will never know if you have to remove last `'\n'` or not.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I've already tested it an it solves my problem.  Thanks for working through it with me.

Comment: BTW: you can also use `sys.stdout.write()` instead of `print()` and then you don't have problem with `'\n'` and with spaces which ar added by print when you use comma.